# Python - Pyinstaller exe file doen't work: Unable to import required dependencies numpy

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pyinstaller

I created a python script to **scrape** data online.
The modules I used are

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas   
import datetime
import xlsxwriter
```

After I generated the `exe` file by pyinstaller, my programme does not run properly to get the data.
I think there is an issue with pandas.
I uninstalled and reinstalled pandas and numpy as instructed in the error message.
My current pandas is 0.25.1 and numpy is 1.18.0. I use the terminal in VS code to get the exe file and I have Anaconda installed in my pc.

Below is the error message:

Error message

```
This programme was build by WL.
Would you like to get the price of the property on sale within 1 miles radius around Buckingham Palace?
Please Enter Y or y to get the file: y
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "RightmoveScraping.py", line 16, in <module>
  File "c:\users\tat\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_imporers.py", line 621, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
ImportError: Unable to import required dependencies:
numpy:

IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!

Importing the numpy c-extensions failed.
- Try uninstalling and reinstalling numpy.
- If you have already done that, then:
 1. Check that you expected to use Python3.8 from "C:\Users\tat\Desktop\Python\dist\RightmoveScraping.exe",
    and that you have no directories in your PATH or PYTHONPATH that can interfere with the Python and numpy version "1.8.0" you're trying to use.
 2. If (1) looks fine, you can open a new issue at https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues. Please include details on:
     - how you installed Python
     - how you installed numpy
     - your operating system
     - whether or not you have multiple versions of Python installed
     - if you built from source, your compiler versions and ideally a build log

- If you're working with a numpy git repository, try `git clean -xdf` (remove all files not under version control) and rebuild numpy.

Note: this error has many possible causes, so please don't comment on an existing issue about this - open a new one instead.

Original error was: DLL load failed while importing _multiarray_umath: The specified module could not be found.

[1664] Failed to execute scriot RightmoveScraping
```

Comment: Are you on Windows? I had the same problem on Ubuntu and I fixed it by installing  libatlas library: "sudo apt-get install libatlas-base-dev". If you're on Windows, I'm not entirely sure if there is even a libatlas library available.

Comment: Ok, I've just managed to read your attachment, it's very small writing! You are on Windows, I see, which means my solution won't work. I suggest checking out https://scipy.github.io/devdocs/building/windows.html - my suspicion is that you're missing BLAS libraries. If you install scipy manually, as in the link, it may fix it.

Comment: Make sure with version of pyinstaller you are running. If you have installed numpy and pandas modules on an anaconda environment then make sure that you are running pyinstaller from the same environment.

Comment: Did you follow _all_ the advice in the error message?